# How to initialize field from type "const char*" in this case?

Tags: c++, c++11

given class with field `const char* filename;` so that the name of the class is for example MyClass.

```
#include <cstring>
class MyClass{
const char* filename;
public:
       MyClass(const char* name);
};
```

How can I initialize the field  `filename` by `name`?
NOTE: I must do it with `strcpy` function.
Is there a way to do this with a initialization list?

Comment: Why do you want to use an initialization list if you have to use `strcpy`?

Comment: Your problem has no responsible solution: either you need storage for the string as part of your type, in which case you need additional data members, or you need to allocate storage dynamically, in which case you are missing declarations for the necessarily user-defined destructor. Whatever you do, you will need to extend your class definition.

Comment: @Jodocus Because that according to what that I reed in some places, while I have a const field, it's must be initialized in initialization list. (it's incorrect?)

Comment: @KerrekSB Can you extend MyClass constructor for that?

Comment: @AskMath: That's not enough. You *will* need additional class members, either data or function members (or both).

Comment: Your field is not const. The buffer where the field is supposed to point at is const.

Comment: Alternatively, if you can ensure that instances of `MyClass` never outlive the arguments passed to initialise them, and then `MyClass::MyClass(const char* name) : filename(name) {}` is OK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this with a initialization list?

There is, you need to use [`strdup`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/experimental/dynamic/strdup) function:

```
class MyClass {
    const char* filename;
public:
    MyClass(const char* name)
        : filename(strdup(name))
    {
        if(!filename)
            throw std::bad_alloc(); // strdup failed.
    }

    ~MyClass() {
        free(const_cast<char*>(filename));
    }

    MyClass(MyClass const&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass const& b) = delete;
};
```

Comment: You meet way to do it with `strcpy`?

Comment: @AskMath You can implement `my_strdup` with `strlen`, `malloc` and `memcpy`. `strcat` is unnecessary because you already know the length, so you just do `memcpy`.

Comment: @AskMath But if writing your own function, prefer `new []` and in destructor then `delete[]`...

Comment: @Aconcagua As long as memory handling details are hidden from the user of the class, the particular choice of allocation does not matter here. Ideally, `std::string` should be used.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin In the end, truth, new/delete come with some advantages, though: not needing to throw explicitly and not requiring cast (after all, it is the more "C++ish" way...). `std::string` - nothing more to say... Wondering why no one mentioned it in the answers...

Comment: Why that complicated and completely useless cast in the dtor?

Comment: @Deduplicator `free` takes `void*`. `char const*` cannot be converted to `void*` without casting away constness.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the `const`. Still, wouldn't a C-style cast to `void*` be more appropriate?

Comment: @Deduplicator C-style cast is never appropriate in C++. Also, C++ casts document the intent better.

Comment: That's too dogmatic for me. In that specific case, I contend the reverse.

Comment: @Deduplicator [C-style cast does too much](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) making your code more fragile, whereas C++ casts are precise and specific. By never having C-style casts in my code I eliminate this source of fragility from my code and never have to think about C-style casts. So, it is practical, rather than dogmatic.

Comment: In general, explicitness is good, true enough. But imho in this case it takes things too far to loquaciousness. Anyway, best to agree to disagree.

Comment: @Deduplicator Agree to disagree agreeably. Your advice on replacing C++ casts with C-style casts is unreasonable to agree with.

Answer (score 1):

```
MyClass::MyClass(char const* filename)
    : filename(strcpy(new char[strlen(filename) + 1], filename))
    //                                          ^^^ space for trailing 0!
{ }
```

As using new, in case of allocation failure a std::bad_alloc will be thrown and strcpy never be called, so we are fine.

Do not forget to `delete[] filename;` in the destructor (not `free`, you did not `malloc`!), otherwise you have a memory leak.

***Edit*** (stealing the ideas from Maxim's comments...):

Using a lambda, you could profit from the more efficient memcpy:

```
MyClass::MyClass(char const* filename)
    : filename([](char const* value)
      {
          size_t len = strlen(filename) + 1;
          return reinterpret_cast<char*>(memcpy(new char[len], value, len));
      }())
{ }
```

You get all this trouble for free, though, if you switch to `std::string` instead:

```
MyClass
{
    std::string filename;
public:
    MyClass(char const* filename) : filename(filename) { }
};
```

You don't even need an explicit destructor any more (provided there is nothing else to clean up...) – use `filename.c_str()` in a `char const*` getter, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Working with `char*` is very tricky. I recommend you to use string to store `filename`. But you still want to use `char*`. You can try as follows:

```
MyClass(const char* name)
{
  filename = new char[100];
  for(int i=0;name[i]!='\0';i++) 
  {
     filename[i]=name[i];
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you remove `const`?

Comment: @TaQuangTu Instead of removing const, have your own local copy you assign afterwards - instead of for loop, use strcpy (which effectively does the same), get size of allocated string from `name` parameter, otherwise you either allocate too much or - worse - to little memory.

Comment: @Aconcagua: Thank you! I record your advices.